# Print all permutation of a fixed number of integers that adds up to k

Tags: c++, recursion, sum, permutation

Suppose I have an array initialized with 0 of size `n`.

I want to print all permutation of `n` positive integers that adds up to a positive integer `k`.

My code at the moment is printing only some permutations (correct ones, but still missing a few).

For example, for `n = 4` and `k = 3` my code is printing:

```
1 1 1 0
1 1 0 1
1 0 2 0
1 0 1 1
1 0 1 1
1 0 0 2
0 2 1 0
0 2 0 1
0 1 2 0
0 1 1 1
0 1 1 1
0 1 0 2
0 1 2 0
0 1 1 1
0 0 3 0
0 0 2 1
0 0 2 1
0 0 1 2
0 1 1 1
0 1 0 2
0 0 2 1
0 0 1 2
0 0 1 2
0 0 0 3
```

You can see it is missing some permutations. For example: `3 0 0 0` and `0 3 0 0`, among others.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

void printArray(int* a, int arraySize){
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        std::cout << a[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int currentSum(int* a, int arraySize){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        sum += a[i];
    return sum;
}

void printAll(int* a, int arraySize, int k, int beg){
    for(int i = beg; i < arraySize; i++){
        if(currentSum(a, arraySize) == k)
            printArray(a, arraySize);
        else{
            a[i]++;
            printAll(a, arraySize, k, beg+1);
            a[i]--;

        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int k = 3; //array must add up to k, exactly
    int arraySize = 4;
    int* a = new int[arraySize];
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        a[i] = 0;
    printAll(a, arraySize, k, 0);
}
```

Comment: I recommend using a debugger to step through your code statement by statement, watching values in variables.

Comment: Comment out all your code until you have a program that prints all the permuations.  Get this working.  You can then add up the digits with `int numerical_value = text_number[i] - '0';`.

Comment: These things are not called permutations. 0 is not a positive integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone needs this in the future...

I followed [Thomas Matthews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225074/thomas-matthews)'s suggestion and started digging for solutions that shows all permutations (with repetitions).

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403049/3585576) that exactly does that. I just had to adapt a little bit my code and it is now working correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class Iter>
bool next_variation(Iter first, Iter last, const typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type max){
    if(first == last) return false;
    Iter i(last); --i;
    if(*i < max) { ++(*i); return true; }
    while( i != first ){
        *i = 0;
        --i;
        if(*i < max) { ++(*i); return true; }
       }
    return false;
}

void printVector(std::vector<int> a){
    for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = a.begin(); it!= a.end(); ++it)
        std::cout << *it << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int currentSum(std::vector<int> a){
    int sum = 0;
    for(std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = a.begin(); it!= a.end(); ++it)
        sum += *it;
    return sum;
}

void printAll(std::vector<int> a, int k){
    do{
        if(currentSum(a) == k)
            printVector(a);
      }
    while( next_variation(a.begin(), a.end(), a.size()) );
}

int main(){
    int k = 3; //array must add up to k, exactly
    int arraySize = 4;

    std::vector<int> a(arraySize,0); // Initialized with 0
    printAll(a, k);

}
```

And the output is:

```
0 0 0 3
0 0 1 2
0 0 2 1
0 0 3 0
0 1 0 2
0 1 1 1
0 1 2 0
0 2 0 1
0 2 1 0
0 3 0 0
1 0 0 2
1 0 1 1
1 0 2 0
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
1 2 0 0
2 0 0 1
2 0 1 0
2 1 0 0
3 0 0 0
```

as expected.

Comment: Since this question is tagged C++ I would recommend using [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) instead

Comment: I thought about that @user2176127. I might be wrong but at least from the example given there, it does not seem to provide permutations with repetitions. I might be wrong though.

Comment: Well it does return permutations, aka n! possibilities to arrange the tuple you provided: https://ideone.com/3m1LvR
I'm not sure if permutation is the correct terminology for what you are doing here.

Comment: @user2176127 Maybe the wording in my question is not good (any edit is very welcome). However, I need "permutations" such as `1111`.

Comment: This assumes that all numbers in the aray are no larger than the array size, is this what you intend? IOW what is the answer for k=5 and n=2?

Comment: This is also a very inefficient method. Try k=2, n=10 for example. There are exactly 55 solutions. How long will it take for your program to find them? What about k=4, n=40? (123410 solutions)

Comment: You are correct @n.m. , for your example the output should be `0 5`, `5 0`, `1 4`, `4 1`, `2 3` and `3 2`.

Comment: Yes, it is very inefficient. However I could not find any solution. If you do, please feel free to share

Comment: You need a list of solutions for sum=k and array size=n. Think how you could build the list from solutions for array size=n-1 and different sums.

Answer (score 0):

You only increment `a[0]` *once*, because only the first call to `printAll` will have a `beg` value of 0.  `a[1]` can be incremented twice, `a[2]` three times, etc.

You need to alter the looping in `printAll` to be able to increment `a[i]` multiple times.

Comment: How do I know how many times I should iterate in the `i-th` iteration?